# Background data message - FCM - Expo

Tags: android, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging, expo

I use Expo (SDK 39) and FCM. I have to process data messages, regardless of state (foreground, background, killed, phone locked).

When a new data message arrives, I must process the data and perform an action (example: play a sound, like an alarm). Automatically, without prior user interaction.

I've been searching for hours but I can't find anything. The docs don't talk about some way of creating a listener for background (`addNotificationResponseReceivedListener` needs user interaction, it doesn't work for me)